# how to catch firestore permission denied exception when the user doesn't have enough permissions to write to the database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

When I try to write to database with a user account that doesn't have write permission I get this exception as expected

> Exception has occurred.
> PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_firestore, com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., {code: permission-denied, message: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.}))

But I am unable to catch it.

Calling this Method causes the exception

```
Future<void> addRecord(Product product) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("products")
          .doc()
          .set(product.toMap())
          .catchError((err) {
        print("error is" + err.toString());
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("eee" + e.toString());
    }
  }
```

This exception is I believe caught as in the console I am getting this message:

> eee[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

But there is one more message in the console

> W/Firestore(12930): (21.4.3) [Firestore]: Write failed at products/SPeUO9260uCoIfpDsSag: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Comment: I assume you are using [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/). In that case, in this [example](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/), to catch properly there is ```catchError``` instead just ```catch```. Maybe this could help you to catch properly the error.

Comment: Even after adding catchError I'm still getting same exception

Comment: I have the same problem here, but then by using a Stream. Thanks to this, I will never get a response back because somewhere before the .catchError, this is already handled.